# Selecting if a person has a specific kind of item

Tags: sql

I'm trying to write a SQL query that will return a user and a specific value based on if at least one record in the column matches the requirement.

I've thrown together this table below to give an example of my problem. I want to get a value of 'TRUE' back for every user who has any rows colored red.

| User | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | red |
| 1 | blue |
| 1 | blue |
| 2 | red |
| 3 | blue |
| 3 | blue |

The output should look like this

| User | Color |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | TRUE |
| 2 | TRUE |
| 3 | FALSE |

Let me know if there's any elaboration needed. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't know why the tables aren't displaying properly but I hope it's still legible enough to display the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you can do it in SQL Server:

```
select u.User, isnull(max(case when c.Color = 'Red' then 'True' else 'False' end), 'False') Color
from users u
left join Color c
on c.user = u.user
group by u.User
order by u.User
```

Comment: I think this answer assumes false is greater than true.  Also, what if there is a users that is not in the usercolor table?

Comment: @Hogan ok, changed to have 2 tables. 'True' is greater than 'False' since they are strings.

Answer (score 1):

You have one table, right? Since True is greater than False in a Max() case expression, then this works.

```
create table my_data (
  userid integer, 
  color varchar(20)
  );

insert into my_data values 
(1, 'red'), 
(1, 'blue'), 
(1, 'blue'), 
(2, 'red'), 
(3, 'blue'), 
(3, 'blue'), 
(4, null), 
(5, null), 
(5, 'red');
```

```
select userid, 
 max(case when color = 'red' then 'True' else 'False' end) as has_red
from my_data
group by userid
```

| userid | has_red |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | True |
| 2 | True |
| 3 | False |
| 4 | False |
| 5 | True |

Answer (score 0):

This will get you all users in usercolor table.

```
SELECT DISTINCT User
FROM UserColor
```

But this won't work -- what if there is a user that isn't in the usercolor table?  Then you need to select from a table that has all of them -- like this

```
SELECT DISTINCT User
FROM UserTable
```

Then you join that table to user color and when you have a red show it.

```
SELECT 
  U.User, 
  CASE WHEN UserColor.User IS NOT NULL THEN 'True' ELSE 'False' END as COLOR
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT User
  FROM UserTable 
) AS U
LEFT JOIN UserColor ON U.User = UserColor.User AND UserColor.Color = 'Red'
```